# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numba.decorators'

Tags: python, numba, librosa

While importing librosa, I am facing this error, even after installing numba distinctively. Can anyone solve this error quickly???

I have tried uninstalling librosa and then reinstalling it again 5 times. Also tried installing numba but it just shows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numba.decorators'".

Comment: Have you tried using a virtual environment? Essentially, this would be similar to a clean install of Python

Answer (score 2):

You have incompatible versions of `librosa` and `numba`.

For example librosa version <= 0.7.2 will have this issue if used with numba >= 0.50.0. References: [Import librosa gives "no module named numba.decorators", how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851675/import-librosa-gives-no-module-named-numba-decorators-how-to-solve),  https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1160

But librosa 0.7.x is very old, so the first step would be to attempt to upgrade librosa. `pip install librosa --upgrade`